# sql query to get max date from multiple columns of multiple table in db2

Tags: sql, db2

I have multiple tables having date_modified column, and I need to create a view using all these tables but date_modified should be max of date_modified of these tables.

```
    table1 
    id vendor_number fiscal_year date_created date_modified
    1    124           2021        2021/11/01   2021/11/02
    2    231           2021        2021/11/01   2021/11/03 
    3    232           2021        2021/11/02   NULL
    4    234           2021        2021/11/02   NULL
    
    table2 
    id fiscal_year discount_amt date_created date_modified
    1  2021          10.30      2021/11/01   2021/11/03
    2  2021          15.23      2021/11/01   2021/11/02
    3  2021          17.45      2021/11/02   2021/11/02
    4  2021          18.49      2021/11/02   NULL
    
    table3
    id vendor_number date_created date_modified
    1  124           2021/11/01   2021/11/04
    2  231           2021/11/01   2021/11/01
    3  232           2021/11/01   2021/11/03
    4  234           2021/11/02   2021/11/03

    Required Output :
    
    id|fiscal_year|discount_amt|vendor_number|date_created|date_modified
    1 | 2021      |  10.30     | 124         | 2021/11/01 | 2021/11/04
    2 | 2021      |  15.23     | 231         | 2021/11/01 | 2021/11/03
    3 | 2021      |  17.45     | 232         | 2021/11/02 | 2021/11/03
    4 | 2021      |  18.49     | 234         | 2021/11/02 | 2021/11/03
```

VIEW SQL:

```
CREATE VIEW view_data
AS
  SELECT T1.id, T1.fiscal_year, T2.discount_amt, T3.vendor_number, T1.date_created, max(multiple date_modified columns..from multiple tables..)
    FROM   table1 AS T1
             LEFT JOIN table2 AS T2
                    ON T1.id = T2.id
             LEFT JOIN T3 v
                    ON T1.vendor_number = T3.vendor_number;
```

Comment: What's the rule for `date_created`? What's wrong with a simple `select id, max (date_modified) as date_modified from (select id, date_modified from table1 union all select id, date_modified from table2 union all select id, date_modified from table3) group by id` statement for that?

Comment: I need to create a view having max of date_modified from multiple table.. I have added a sample view definition and also updated the table structure. `date_created` will used from primary table` table1`. This needs to be done in DB2.

Comment: You use `fiscal_year` column for joining `tabl1` and `table2` but show 2 output rows from this join, whereas it must be 4 rows, since both tables has 2 rows each with the same `fiscal_year`. Can you explain, why, say, the 1-rst row of `table1` joins to the 1-st (and not to the 2-nd one) row of `table2`? Didn't you messed up the join columns?

Comment: yes, may be the example I have given is not what I actually have .. I just wanted to achieve that date_modified column should be max of all the date_modified column of all table. Please ignore the joins or table data , the output is just to show the required result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `id` columns are keys of each table you can join them (using full outer join maybe) and then use `GREATEST()` to get the latest date.

For example:

```
create view v as 
select
  coalesce(a.id, b.id, c.id) as id,
  b.fiscal_year,
  b.discount_amt,
  a.date_created,
  greatest(a.date_modified, b.date_modified, c.date_modified) as date_modified
from table1 a
full join table2 b on b.id = a.id
full join table3 c on c.id = b.id or c.id = a.id
```

**EDIT**: If your version of DB2 doesn't implement `GREATEST()` you can replace it with the [rather long] `CASE` clause:

```
  case when a.date_modified > b.date_modified then
    case when a.date_modified > c.date_modified 
         then a.date_modified else c.date_modified end
  else
    case when b.date_modified > c.date_modified 
         then b.date_modified else c.date_modified end
  end
```

Alternatively, you can implement the function yourself. It's pretty straightforward. For example:

```
create function greatest(in a date, in b date) returns date
language sql
begin
  if a > b then return a; end if;
  return b;
end
//
```

See running example of this custom function at [db<>fiddle 1](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=1cf84738c1d4548bd04662ed23c639ce).

**EDIT #2: Dealing with nulls**

Nulls are not values, and the behavior of the database is correct. In the presence of an unknown date the engine cannot determine which date is greater and returns `UNKNOWN` -- in the form of a null.

Now, if you want nulls to behave as in programming languages like C, Java, PHP, then you can either 1) Use a lot of `CASE`/`COALESCE` clauses or you can simply modify your custom function to wotk as you please. Below is an example of the modified custom function:

```
create function mygreatest(in a date, in b date) returns date
language sql
begin
  if a is null then return b; end if;
  if b is null then return a; end if;
  if a > b then return a; end if;
  return b;
end
```

Then, you can see it in action:

```
with data (x, y) as (
  select date '2021-07-01', date '2021-12-01' from sysibm.sysdummy1
  union all select date '2021-07-01', null from sysibm.sysdummy1
  union all select null, date '2021-12-01' from sysibm.sysdummy1
  union all select null, null from sysibm.sysdummy1
)
select mygreatest(x, y) as g from data;
```

Result:

```
G
----------
2021-12-01
2021-07-01
2021-12-01
null
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=bf1093050326b0a06f1cd9f694aea923).

Comment: I am using DB2 v9.1, `GREATEST()` is available in DB2 9.7v

Comment: @PoojaGupta Added a couple of solutions for version 9.1.

Comment: `CASE` is not giving proper result as the columns are having `null` values.

Comment: @PoojaGupta Please update the question and add rows of sample data with nulls, and the expected result.

Comment: I have updated the example with null values, also I have updated my db2 version to  version 10.1, So now greatest() is working.. but the date_modified column contains null values, so greatest() is also returning null value if any table column value is null.

Comment: @PoojaGupta See modified example to deal with your specific requirements.